# Quadratic equation - What is the value of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

"Find out the value of x by this equation: $(x+a)^2 = (2a-3x)^2$". (The answer should by the way, according to my book, be

$x1 = 0.25a$

$x2 = 1.5a$

Here's how far I've gotten:

$(x+a)^2 = (2a-3x)^2$

$x^2 + 2ax + a^2 = 4a^2 - 12ax + 9x^2$

$x^2 = 3a^2 + 9x^2 - 14ax$

After that I'm stuck. I haven't done any problem like this (ever) before, so I don't know what to do. I did try to "formulate" the equation differently to see if I would have an easier time solving it like this:

$-8x^2 + 14ax - 3a^2 = 0$

But I honestly don't know what do after that. I'd love it if someone could thoroughly explain the steps I need to do in order to get the value of $x$.

Comment: $a^2=b^2 $then $$a=\pm b$$

Comment: $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then $$x_1,x_2=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No quadratic equation really required here:

\begin{align*}
(x + a)^2 = (2a - 3x)^2 & \iff x + a = \pm (2a - 3x)\\
                       & \iff x + a = \begin{cases}
                                      2a - 3x\\
                                      3x - 2a
                                      \end{cases}\\
                       & \iff x = \begin{cases}
                                    \dfrac{a}{4}\\[0.2 mm]
                                    \dfrac{3a}{2}
                                    \end{cases} 
\end{align*}

Comment: no quadratic equation really required ever

Comment: Certainly, but sometimes it's hidden and the formulae are handy. But here it's the basic case,  which the whole theory relies upon.

Comment: Right I guess I'm overcomplicating it

Comment: It's often the case for each of us. It should be a reflex to check if any solution may be simplified

Comment: I used the align environment to align your equations since they were overlapping.  This is certainly the simplest solution.

Comment: Were they? I didn't see anything on my own screen, but  noticed it was very tight. May be that depended on the browser. Anyway, thank you for having taken care of doing it!

Answer (score 4):

$8x^2-14ax+3a^2=0$

Use the quadratic equation

$x=\frac{14a±\sqrt{(14a)^2-4(8)(3a^2)}}{16}$

$=\frac{14a±10a}{16}$

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Treat symbol $a$ as if it is a constant.

$$ -8x^2 + 14ax - 3a^2 =  ( 4 x -a)( -2 x + 3 a)= 0,  $$

$$ x = ( 3 a/2, a/4 ) $$